# How to set auto swipe for viewPager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my application I should use `viewPager` and I want set **auto swipe** between pages in `viewPager`. for this I write below code :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES - 1) {
            currentPage = 0;
        }
        boxOfficeViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
    }
};

timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(Update);
    }
}, 5000, 3000);
```

with above code I can set auto swipe in `viewPager`, but swipe speed is very fast! I set **5000ms for delay time** but is very fast.
I set 0ms for delay time and not change it. 
**No difference** between 5 and 5000 for this speed!!!

How can I set slow speed for auto swipe in `viewPager`?

Comment: Do you want to increase swipe interval or speed of swipe?

Comment: @RonakThakkar, yes , I want slowly swipe between pages. can you help me my friend?

Comment: You can try this library https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager

Answer (score 0):

First 0 means change immediately then after 10 seconds delay change this

```
timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(Update);
    }
}, 0, 10000);
```

Try this and tell me works or not?